# Kerberos-SSO with Liferay 6.2 and JBoss

Tags: jboss, liferay, single-sign-on, liferay-6, kerberos

is it possible at all to configure **Liferay 6.2** on a **JBoss-Server** so that Liferay can use **Single-Sign-On with Kerberos authentication** ?

Do i have to configure Liferay's portal.ext.properties or standalone.xml within JBoss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely configure Liferay with JBoss.
https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/installing-liferay-on-jboss-7-1

And Kerberos is configured at your HTTP Server.
http://blog.dbi-services.com/kerberos-sso-with-liferay-61/

And then Kerberos is referred by your liferay app through hook.
https://github.com/anthonyboutinov/kerberos-liferay

Comment: once you confirm the hints/solution, I would recommend you to approve the answer.